# Trouble with wifi connection on ubuntu 22.04 (laptop)

Tags: networking, drivers

I'm having really slow wifi speed using my internal adapter, I've tried using an external USB wifi adapter and that seemed to fixed the issue (sometimes, others it doesn't).

I should mention that I had troubles getting to a wifi connection at all when I first installed Ubuntu. After few restarts and little search on the internet I found that I should enable the driver from the "Additional Drivers" app, the one shown below:

[image]

Do you have any clues where I should look into?